# slideToggle callback function not working

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a button that uses the slideToggle() method to show hide an element.  I am just trying to change the value of the button once the slideup is complete.  I have tried using the callback function to change this value but I just can't get it to work.

```
$('#toggleFilters').click(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    $('.formSelect').slideToggle(['slow','swing'], function() {

    if($(this).is(":hidden")) {
        $(el).val('Show Filters');
    } else {
        $(el).val('Hide Filters');
    }
    });
});
```

If anybody can point me in the right direction that would be appreciated?

Cheers
Graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I didn't bother with looking at the slideToggle() call back in the end and just went with the classToggle function instead.

```
$('.showHideFilters').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('shown');
        $('.formSelect').slideToggle(['slow','swing']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $('#toggleFilters').click(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        $('.formSelect').slideToggle(['slow','swing'], function() {

        if($(this).is(':visible')) {
            el.val('Hide Filters');
        } else {

            el.val('Show Filters');
        }
        });
    });
```